# Is there a way to hydrate objects without looping through result sets twice?

Tags: php, oop, db2-400, hydration

If I use a Hydrator to put the values of my query results into an instance of my Model I'm going to have to loop through the results twice (once to hydrate each row/object and then again when I actually use the results).

I know there are various `PDO_FETCH_*` modes such as `FETCH_INTO` and `FETCH_CLASS` which seem to achieve the same functionality.  The only difference I can see is the potential to manipulate the data during hydration.

I'm just trying to figure out the reasoning behind using hydrators when they require an additional iteration through the result set. I feel there has to be some reason or method to make that additional iteration acceptable and I'm curious what it is.  I'm not sure why a programming pattern like hydrators is so populate because on the surface it seems like a waste in most situations.  Is manipulating the data during hydration the only reason to use Hydrators?

**"Find All" method from mapper:**

(`$this->hydrator` is an instance of `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable`, but can be replaced with any other hydrator for the purpose of this question.)

```
/*
 * @return array|PagesInterface[]
 */
public function findAll(){
    //Perform select
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CMSMAIN";
    $stmt = $this->dbal->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if($result === true){
        //$stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $modelGoesHere); //Using FETCH_CLASS populates the model directly eliminating the need for the extra iteration.
        $records = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $rows = array();
        foreach($records as $value){  //First Loop to hydrate
            $rows[] = $this->hydrator->hydrate($value, new PagesModel($this->logger));
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    return array();
}
```

Comment: I am not talking about what you do now. Just  generating your wanted objects directly from the array returned from the 'fetchAll()' statement? The `fromArray()` is just what I am used to :) My understanding of the issue is: that the column names in the array returned from the database don't match the property names in the object, so somewhere there is a need to convert column names to property names? i.e. store the column values from the database in the correct properties in the object.

Comment: I suspect the that using a 'custom hydrator' would be the most appropriate way so as to be more consistent  with the 'standard way' of retrieving data. Just seems a lot of effort for a couple of tables?